# Unable to connect to protected Access DB in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssis, office365, etl

I have an Access DB (part of Office 365) with extension (.accdb).  This database is protected by a password.  I'm trying to create a connection to this Access db in SSIS but it keeps failing when I do a "Test Connection".

I'm using the following provider in my connection:

1. Native OLE DB\Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider
2. In the "Jet OLEDB:Database Password" under the "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" section, I enter the password.

But when I click "Test Connection", it fails.

I basically followed this link:

- [Password Protected Access DB and SSIS](http://dailyitsolutions.blogspot.com/2010/02/password-protected-access-and-ssis.html)

**The error message is:**

> Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. Cannot open database. it may not be a database that your application recognizes or the file may be corrupt

Does anyone know why?

Thank you

Comment: The error message is: test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider.  cannot open database.  it may not be
a database that your application recognizes or the file may be corrupt

Answer (score 0):

The main error is:

> Cannot open database. it may not be a database that your application recognizes or the file may be corrupt

So i don't think it is a password related error, it sounds like your database is corrupted. Try opening the database manually, run the Compact and repair process, and Save As new copy

### Helpful articles

- [Where is Compact and Repair in Microsoft Access 2007, 2010, 2013 and 2016](http://www.addintools.com/documents/access/where-is-compact-repair.html)
- [Fix MS Access Database Error 3049: Cannot Open Access Database](https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/fix-ms-access-cannot-open-database-error/)
- [Cannot open database “. It may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_other-mso_2007/cannot-open-database-it-may-not-be-a-database-that/9109c4d9-eb2e-4798-a2bf-919dace97dff)
- [Compact and repair a database](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Compact-and-repair-a-database-6ee60f16-aed0-40ac-bf22-85fa9f4005b2)

Answer (score 0):

In Access, I get the error 3049: Cannot open database '' when I'm adding bulk records and specifically when these records have Access attachments. These attachments are stored as a byte array and may be rather numerous and each could be sizeable - a megabyte for a picture is not uncommon. When I exceed 2GB of Access database size, the error is 3049 and it can happen quite randomly.